# Open 2 links in 1 click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

would it be possible to open 2 links in 1 click ?
always having a syntax error when it comes to this thing

so 1 have this links

```
echo '<td><a href="appdone.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' "><div align="center"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" width="38" height="25" /></div></a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' "><div align="center"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" width="38" height="25" /></div></a></td>';
```

is it possible to make
 `href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '` 
and 
`href="appdone.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '` be clicked on the same link?

Also I would also love the other one on popup if its possible

```
<a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' " onclick="javascript:void window.open('appdone.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ','1394380018533','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">CLICK</a>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You've repeatedly said that you get getting an error … how about telling what that error is?

Comment: Syntax Error @Quentin

Comment: What's the exact error message? Which line is it on? Is it a PHP error or a JavaScript error?

Comment: When I paste the code @ Dreamweaver it gives me syntax error in the entire line @Quentin

Comment: I've never heard anything good about Dreamweaver's error checking capabilities. What happens when you test it in a browser with a proper PHP enabled webserver?

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'appdone' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' `

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the last line of code you shared … which seems to start half way through a statement making it hard to debug. The problem appears to be with your quoting as you seem to have JS embedded in HTML embedded in PHP which leads an an inevitable mess. I'd drop out of PHP mode to output HTML (only adding `<?php` at the point where I need data from a variable) and move the JS to a `<script>` element with `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing PHP, JS and HTML code without using the appropriate tags. Give this a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEditEntry (id) {
  window.open('appdone.php?id='+id, '1394380018533', 'width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');
  location.href='edit.php?id='+id;
}
</script>

<td><a href="javascript:addEditEntry(<?php print $row['id']; ?>)"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" width="38" height="25" /></a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks but it still give me a syntax error @SaschaM78

Comment: @Wolfstein could you post your updated code on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/yg3mH/2/), one problem was the additional php-tag inside the echo'd string.

Comment: tried and still giving me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: The code in the updated fiddle works for me. Check the line number the error is referring to and double-check if it's the `echo ...` command.

Comment: @Wolfstein any news about your problem?